# Updating ListView in a Fragment from OnOptionsItemSelected

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments

I have a HomeActivity which extends Activity that contains Actionbar items. The HomeActivity has 1 fragment (StatusFragment which extends Fragment).  In the Fragment there is a ListView which uses a custom ArrayAdapter and a method call to supply the data.

```
private ParseUser[] GetUsers(){
    final ParseQuery<ParseUser> query = ParseUser.getQuery();
    ParseUser[] usersArray;

    try {
        List<ParseUser> users = query.find();
        usersArray = users.toArray(new ParseUser[users.size()]);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        usersArray = null;
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return usersArray;
}
```

I'm having trouble getting the ListView to update from the OnOptionsItemSelected callback.

```
case R.id.home_ab_refresh:
    StatusFragment pFrag = (StatusFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("mFragment");
    pFrag.users = pFrag.GetUsers();
    pFrag.mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    return true;
```

1) Is this an appropriate way to access the Fragment from the Actionbar items (HomeActivity)?

2) Is there a better way to design this code?

Thanks much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Re 1) I probably wouldn't do a `findFragmentByTag()` every time, and instead just stick the fragment into a member variable of the activity during the activity's `onCreate()`.

The main issue with the code is something else:

```java
   pFrag.users = pFrag.GetUsers();
   pFrag.mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Here you violate the object-oriented design principle of [loose coupling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter). The `HomeActivity` is too intimately bound to the implementation details of the `StatusFragment`. What you should do instead is move that code into the fragment and expose it as a single, public method that is named for the *intent* (goal, purpose) of the action, not its *implementation*.

```java
   // In HomeActivity
   pFrag.reloadData();

   // In the fragment
   public void reloadData() {
       this.users = pFrag.GetUsers();
       this.mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
   }
```

This way, it's easier to reuse the status fragment elsewhere. More importantly, it's easier to **evolve** that fragment, you can now completely change the internals without having to change the host activity. This is cleaner from a design perspective.

Re 2) Aside from the issue I already mentioned, you should consider returning an empty array rather than `null` when an exception occurs. It's generally a better idea to return empty array/collection from finder methods, because people tend to immediately use the result for an iterator or an `addAll()` or something like that, without null-checking it first.

Comment: Thanks very much for the feedback!  This is extremely useful and concise information.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you dont make a nullpointer check, since you cant be certain that the FragmentManager will actually return a validFragment.

you can however just catch the onOptionsMenuSelected event in the fragment itself, which will result in a much more capsulated code.

Besides that, when do you refresh the ListView? Wouldnt it make sense to update the listview automatically once the new data has arrived?

Comment: +1 for handling the options menu via the fragment, I had overlooked that.